# How to control the size of <label> element in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, label

I want to make  element to be the same size of box, but the size of label is shorter than I expected. Also, "width" is not working in the React.

How can I solve this problem?

```
const DragDrop = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <div className="DragDrop" style={{ height: `${30 + 5 * files.length}vh` }}>
      <input
        type="file"
        accept="audio/flac, audio/mp3, audio/ogg, audio/wav"
        id="fileUpload"
        style={{ display: "none" }}
        multiple={true}
        onChange={onChangeFiles}
      />
      <div className={isDragging ? "DragDrop-File-Dragging" : "DragDrop-File"}>
        <label htmlFor="fileUpload">
          <Box ref={dragRef} className={"DragDrop-FileBox"}>
            <Typography variant="h5">
              {isDragging
                ? "Drop here!"
                : "Drag files"}
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This code shows example like this.
[image]

If I remove  element, the result shows like this. (just I expected.)
[image]

And here is scss file I used.

```
@mixin filledStyle() {
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
  }
  
  @mixin alignCenter() {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }

  @mixin alignCenterVertical() {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .DragDrop {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20vh;
    @include alignCenter();
    
    &-File {
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      border: 2px dashed grey;
      border-radius: 10px;
      
      @include alignCenterVertical();
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 0.12s ease-in;
  
      &-Dragging {
        width: 100%;
        @include filledStyle();
      }
    }

    &-FileBox {
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      border: 2px dashed grey;
      border-radius: 10px;
      
      @include alignCenterVertical();
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 0.12s ease-in;
  
    }
  }
```

Comment: Share your code in cidesandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Make forcefully take the label width 100% via width 100% in the label

```
 .DragDrop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  @include alignCenter();
   label{
    width:100%;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `<label>` elements are *inline*, by default (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

*inline* elements can have neither width nor height (ignored).

Set `display: inline-block` to overcome this problem.